# Can we add some additional information in a file?

Tags: jquery, html, file, file-upload, data-uri

I want a file to carry some additional information like a Id of a record.

Can we add some additional metadata or anything in a file?

Can we add some additional byte stream which do not corrupt the file?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Tried creating a `json` object , adding file object , additional properties to `json` object ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write metadata to files using what is called **extended attributes**. 
Here is a wiki link for more information on that (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes)

It depends on what language are you going to read and write to this attributes.

For example in **PHP** you can use the PECL library xattr's function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.xattr-set.php)

On **Node.JS** you would use a library like that fs-xattr (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-xattr)

Notes:

1. Keep in mind that different file systems have different specs.
2. You have limited size depending on the filesystem
3. There are specifications for particular file extensions and different ways to write to them depending on your programming language.

For example there is **Exif** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#Example) for JPEG images.

Or ID3 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) for MP3 and etc.

Comment: I am using jquery to read and write into a existing file.

I have some files in a system which are related to there parent. I want to add parent Id into a file so that I can keep track of file about its parent.

I appreciate your effort but I did not get much information about my issue from above links.

Can you please explain it little more.